# Build NuGet package on Linux that targets .NET Framework

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I want to create a NuGet package that can simultaneously and explicitly target *both* .NET Framework 4.6.2 and .Net Standard 1.5. Here's an abbreviated .csproj file from VS 2017:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net462;netstandard1.5</TargetFrameworks>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

When I execute the dotnet build and pack commands from my local Windows machine, the NuGet package is created perfectly well as expected.

**However**, when I attempt to execute the same dotnet commands on Linux, I receive the following error:

> /opt/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1111,5):
>   error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" were not found.  To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.  Note that assemblies will
>   be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies.  Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

It then dawned on me that there aren't any regular .NET Framework assemblies on the Linux box (let alone . Thus, it appears that I won't be able to use Linux to build my NuGet package. I searched around for a "Targeting Pack", but it's only available for Windows.

At the risk of sounding naïve, is anyone successfully building NuGet packages on Linux that can target .NET Framework?

Comment: Currently they don't put that scenario under consideration. So you will have to use Windows.

Comment: This is tracked by an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335) I opened months ago. I posted an answer based on the discussions happened there.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks for that GitHub link, that was immensely informative.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The distribution of the .NET CLI doesn't contain any reference assemblies for .NET Framework so its version of MSBuild cannot resolve the needed compile-time assets. This scenario is [tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335) though and has worked before the migration to MSBuild (the CLI could use mono's reference assemblies).

There are a few alternatives though that can be used to build your library on non-windows machines:

**1. Use mono 5+ to build the library.**

This is probably the most stable path.

Mono 5 and higher contains the needed build logic to build .NET Standar and .NET Core applications. On linux, mono's msbuild may need to be installed as a separate package. So instead of the following commonly used commands

```
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet publish -c Release
```

you would use mono's msbuild to do the following:

```
msbuild /t:Restore
msbuild
msbuild /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release
```

**Pack workaround for mono < 5.2:**

The only limitation is that mono (< 5.2) cannot produce NuGet packages out of the box but there is a [workaround involving using the `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` NuGet package](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335#issuecomment-301453493) in the project which allows you to do `msbuild /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Release` by modifying the project file like this (especially note the removed `Sdk="..."` attribute on the `<Project>` element):

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NuGetBuildTasksPackTargets>junk-value-to-avoid-conflicts</NuGetBuildTasksPackTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <!-- All your project's other content here -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack" Version="4.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
</Project>
```

**2. Use the .NET CLI and tell MSBuild to use mono's reference assemblies.**

When building for `net*` target frameworks, you can set the `FrameworkPathOverride` property both as an environment variable or as a property in the csproj file. It needs to point to a set of reference assemblies - mono's reference assemblies can be used here. But some contain a special file (redist list) containing references to other directories which the MSBuild version in the .NET CLI cannot follow. It does work in a lot of scenarios though:

```
export FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/
dotnet build -f net45
```

This was used and [documented by the F# team](https://github.com/dotnet/netcorecli-fsc/wiki/.NET-Core-SDK-rc4#using-net-framework-as-targets-framework-the-osxunix-build-fails).

**3. Use a NuGet package containing reference assemblies.**

On some MyGet feeds, Microsoft publishes NuGet packages containing reference assemblies. They are not published or "official" though so this process may fail at some point in time. However they do [plan to investigate making this path official](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335#issuecomment-299882280).

First create a NuGet.Config file in your solution's directory with to following contents to add the feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <packageSources>
    <add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
 </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Then you can add an item group to add the `PackageReference` to a targeting pack and a `PropertyGroup` to set the path to the reference assemblies like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp1.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <FrameworkPathOverride>$(NuGetPackageFolders)microsoft.targetingpack.netframework.v4.6.1\1.0.1\lib\net461\</FrameworkPathOverride>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TargetingPack.NETFramework.v4.6.1" Version="1.0.1" ExcludeAssets="All" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You can change the `RuntimeIdentifier` for different platforms if you use native assets (e.g. to get `.so` files for linux) or remove it entirely when building libraries.

Comment: The third option should be the ultimate solution now as Microsoft makes it official https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/tree/master/releases/reference-assemblies

Answer (score 9):

You can just add the following to your project file:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net4')) AND '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Core' AND '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

This will allow to build and pack on non-windows systems for .NET Framework.
But you can only run .NET Core targets using `dotnet` CLI on non-windows systems.
So you should also be ready to select a target framework to run on non-windows systems, like this:

```
dotnet run -f netcoreapp2.1
```

Source of the solution: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/33#issuecomment-489264196.
This is a workaround, so it is subject to change in the future.